# unable to read the output to run the next command

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

When this script is executed I get the PID. Now I want to read the output "PID" and run the next command in this way:

```
ps -ef | grep -i PID  
ps -ef | grep -i PID  

while read -r -u10 server port line  
do  
  echo ==========  server: "$server" port: "$port"  ==========  
  ssh -qn "$server" "netstat -tulpunt | grep -E ":$port "" | \
      awk '{print $7}' | grep '/' | awk -F "/" '{print $1}'  
  echo  
done 10< demo
```

Comment: I'm sorry it is not clear what your are trying to do. What are the first two lines supposed to do? Where do you need the PID?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what the script is supposed to do and exactly how it fails. Is PID a variable? A string? Why are you running `ps` twice? Why are you running it at all if you want the PID of a process? What information are you trying to parse from the server? What is in `demo`? What "next command" do you want to run?

Answer (score 1):

- my understanding is that the second part of your code give a PID, and you want to grep it.
- and also the double ps is a typo.

something like

```
while read -r -u10 server port line
do
  echo ==========  server: "$server" port: "$port"  ==========
  pid=$(ssh -qn "$server" "netstat -tulpunt | grep -E ":$port "" | \
      awk '{print $7}' | grep '/' | awk -F "/" '{print $1}'  )
  echo "PID: $pid"
  ssh -qn "$server" "ps -ef | grep $pid"
  echo
done 10< demo
```

notes

- that grep will grep itself ( you may whish to add `| grep -v grep` at the end )
- I am not sure the `$( ... )` syntax can spread lines.

EDIT:

in that case, try

```
ssh -qn "$server" "netstat -tulpunt | awk '/:"$port"/ { split(\$7,A,\"/\" ) ; printf \"ps -p %d\n\",A[1]}' | bash "
```

which is quiet intuitive.

- grep feature of awk `/:"$port"/` will grab the port
- split, will pick the PID in A[1]
- finally, we use `ps -p %d -f --no-headers` to emulate `ps -ef | grep PID`
- and we gave it to remote `bash`

Comment: its working perfectly but do you think i need to connect the server again. it will consume time. and what if the server server is asking password in some case. it will hang & will not get any output